# passing array state to another class react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I am making a lunch picker app for practice, and I wonder how to pass array of state to another class. 
What I want to do is: show all data of array in child screen, so users can check the data by clicking on a button.
However, it seems like my code returns null array instead of getting original array. All codes are in one file, App.js

**Home screen**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
//initial
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isReady: false,
    myMenu: '????',
    menutext: '',
    randomArray: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  };
}

render() {


    return (
      <View style={[styles.mainContainer]}>
        <DetailsScreen menuListAA={this.state.randomArray} />
        <Button
          label="Show all menu"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the menu page route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 0,
              otherParam: 'Show all menu',
            });
          }}
        />

      </View>
```

**Details screen**

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'All menu',
  };

loadMenuList() {
  const allMenuList = this.props.menuListAA;
  return allMenuList.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>);

}

  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView>


        <View style={styles.row}>{this.props.menuListAA}</View>

        <Button
          label="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: <DetailsScreen menuListAA={this.state.randomArray}></DetailsScreen> put this line inside return brackets and try

Comment: When I put that line inside return but outside of view, it gives me an error "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.". When I put it inside <view>, then it says "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."

Comment: Put the above line after this <View style={[styles.mainContainer]}> or above <Button> or I have edited the code for you, Please check

Comment: It doesn't work and it says "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component." even though I tried with your suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with one below :

**Home screen**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
//initial
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isReady: false,
    myMenu: '????',
    menutext: '',
    randomArray: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  };
}

render() {


    return (
      <View style={[styles.mainContainer]}>
        <DetailsScreen menuListAA={this.state.randomArray} />
        <Button
          label="Show all menu"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the menu page route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 0,
              otherParam: 'Show all menu',
            });
          }}
        />

      </View>
```

**Doubts Detail** : replace `View` with `Text` component

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'All menu',
  };

loadMenuList() {
  const allMenuList = this.props.menuListAA;
  return allMenuList.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>);

}

  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView>

//change View with Text as view cannot render characters and error says the same

        <Text style={styles.row}>{this.props.menuListAA}</Text>

        <Button
          label="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data from parent to child by set props for child component like this: `<Child  data={this.state.yourData}  /> //the props name is data`,
then in child component in `componentWillMount()` you can access it:

```
ComponentWillMount(){ 
    this.setState({childData: this.props.data}) // childData is an state of child component,rename it to your own` 
}
```

in some case data maybe changed so we must to check this in `componentDidUpdate()` :

```
componentDidUpdate(){
     if(this.props.data != this.state.childData){ //it is necessary because this function called many time's 
            this.setState({childData: this.props.data})
}
```

if you was in parent & want to give any data from child you must pass a function that returned data as like below:

```
<Child getData={(value)=> console.log(value)} />
```

then in your child you can do this:

```
this.props.getData(anyDataYouWantGetInParent)
```

hope this answer will be helpful,let me know any question
good luck.